# Loop through custom taxanomy in post and display custom fields from posts

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, loop, taxonomy, query-posts

I will try to elaborate the title. I want to make a post, within this post I want to loop through all posts from a custom taxanomy and extract custom fields.

How is this done in the most efficient way?

What I am thinking about is using the template hierarchy:
*single-post-{slug}.php*

Within this I get the content using:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', '{custom template}' ); ?>
```

So in *content-custom-template.php* I will make the loop that goes through all the custom taxanomies.

So as you can see, this will require 2 additional template files for every custom taxanomy I want to do this with (because I need a post for every custom taxanomy).

What I need to know:

- Is there are more efficient/better way?
- How do I make the loop for custom
  taxanomies within the post?

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly, then you would want to create a new loop with a custom WP_Query and within that loop grab your custom fields?

Comment: That is correct !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need set up a new WP_Query in your `content-*.php` with the correct parameters in order to send it into a loop.

```
<?php
   $args = array(
     'tax_query' => array(
             array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'recipes',.
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => 'dessert'
   )));

   $your_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

You can add any other parameters you want/need for this query. You can find more reference on parameters at the WordPress Codex page for [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and add them to the `$args` array.

In my example, `WP_Query` is going to look at the `recipes` taxonomy, it's going to find `recipes` by looking at the slug, and find all posts with the value `dessert`.

Once you have the new WP_Query set up, you then send it into the WordPress loop:

```
<?php
    if ( $your_posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $your_posts->have_posts() ) : $your_posts->the_post();
?>
// Your Post Stuff Goes Here
<?php endwhile; else: ?> <p>Sorry, there are no posts to display</p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

In order to get at your custom fields, I would suggest writing a function in your `functions.php` file to handle this and call it within the loop. That way if you can use it throughout the theme with more ease.

```
<?php
   function my_custom_field( $id, $field_name ) {
      return get_post_meta( $id, $field_name, true );
   }
?>
```

What this function does is access the post's metadata, look for the field name you specify, and returns a single value. If there are multiple values using the same key, then omit the `true` and the function will instead return an array which you can then use a `foreach()` to process that.

So, for example, say your custom field is `'mood'` then the call to the function would be:

```
<?php my_custom_field( $post->ID, 'mood' ); ?>
```

Comment: I <3 you, thank you so much! (i corrected some minor mistakes giving PHP errors btw). :)

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't have time to test it in my environment since I do not have any custom taxonomies set up. Out of curiosity, what was generating errors?

Comment: I have made an edit with the correction. It was just some missing ")" in the first script.

Comment: That's what I get for typing code in notepad :). Thanks for making the correction, I approved it so it's now part of the solution.